What does the following pointer point to?
Hello I'm just trying to understand pointers better. I was playing around with pointers and void pointers and I wrote the following code:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    struct myStruct
    {
        std::vector<int> myVec;
    };
    
    myStruct* myStructPtr = new myStruct();
    
    myStructPtr->myVec.push_back(1);
    myStructPtr->myVec.push_back(2);
    myStructPtr->myVec.push_back(42);
    myStructPtr->myVec.push_back(24024);
    
    {
        int* arr = myStructPtr->myVec.data();
        std::cout << arr << std::endl;
    }
    
    {
        void* arr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(&myStructPtr->myVec); //what does this point to ?
        std::cout << arr << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}

When I ran this through the Online C++ compiler the output was the following :
0x559c14a3bed0
0x559c14a3beb0

They seem to be 32 bits apart. I know that myVec.data() returns a pointer to the underlying array serving as the element storage, but the void* arr pointer I'm not sure what it is really pointing to.

Points to the address of vector class. Not the data of the vector. So basically it points to a class that has (somewhere) another pointer to the data. Side note, if you are a beginning C++, try to avoid (raw) pointers and raw pointer arithmetic and void* really rarely usable in C++ itself (unless you know about type erasure and templates)

I recommend adding what you expect &myStructPtr->myVec to provide the address of to the question. You're probably right, but if you aren't, the question gets a lot easier to answer.


reinterpret_cast<void*> is unnecessary. 2. If you know what int main() { int a; std::cout << &a; } does, then you know the answer. 3. They seem to be 32 bits apart. - this is a wrong assumption.


Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

They are 32 bytes apart.  But this is just a coincidence.

Since you have allocated vector on heap and content of vector is by default is allocated on heap it is possible those two things are close by address. But this is just pure luck that implementation of standard library did that this way. Change reserved size of vector and it can go to completely different address.

The first arr points to the memory address where the vector's data is located in memory.
The second arr points to the memory location of the myVec object.
The proper type should be:
{
    auto vectorObjectAddress = &myStructPtr->myVec; //what does this point to ?
    std::cout << "type is " << typeid(vectorObjectAddress).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << vectorObjectAddress << std::endl;
}

And the output, is PSt6vectorIiSaIiEE witch is a C++ mangled name. Long story short, the type is a vector of int.
https://godbolt.org/z/6zx3nfE4h

"The proper type should be" - in this case, auto would deduce to std::vector<int>*
